# Automatically zip a project after it is saved or the editor is closed?

Tags: webstorm

My company enforces the use of OneDrive for sync and backup.  I'm currently working on a project that has a lot of static data in JSON files.  OneDrive blocks JSON files.

Is there any way built into webstorm that I could automatically zip the project folder when I save it or close the IDE?  This way I could store that zip in the sync folder and have access to it on my desktop and laptop and have a backup.  Not ideal, but better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: I don't know you tool, but most dev environments have the ability to run post build commands.  Maybe that could be an option?

Comment: Check the tags... I hope you're not the one that downvoted it :(

Comment: Also, I don't want to do it on build, but if I have to that's a good idea I guess.

Comment: Speaking of trolls, I resisted commenting on your typo.  It looks like you're calling me a tool :)

Comment: hahaha - that was hilarious .   No, I am saying that I work with a lot of languages (as most do), but I don't know webstorm or jetbrains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71339/discussion-between-scott-beeson-and-anthony-horne).

Comment: Yeah, that didn't do what I thought it did.  It says "move" the discussion to a chat.  I was trying to clean up all our banter.  It just copies it, of course.  Disregard.